# Python script to execute sed command for comparing 2 same log files but ignoring time stamp

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have 2 log files that have same content but different time stamps. I need to compare the 2 files but ignore the time stamp of both files i.e first 20 characters. I have found the command as:

```
diff -I '^#' <(sed -r 's/^((.){20})/#\1\n/' 1.log) <(sed -r 's/^((.){20})/#\1\n/' 2.log)
```

But how do I write this command in python script?
When I try to execute the above one, I get error as invalid command. I'm quite new to python so please go easy on me.

Comment: Use [subprocess interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to execute shell commands, for example `check_output`.

Comment: not the reply for python issue but unless you realy need to keep unused timestamp you can simplify with `diff <(sed 's/.\{20\}//' 1.log) <(sed 's/.\{20\}//' 2.log)`